# Pybot - redirect test library print statements to the console

Tags: python, logging, robotframework

Test.robot,

```
*** Settings ***
Library roppie

*** Test Cases ***
Log Test
  Robot Print
```

roppie.py,

```
def robot_print():
   print "this is a testlib log for robot test - Test.robot"
```

Now, when i run `pybot Test.robot`, the print statements are printed in log.html. But I am interested in seeing these print statements in the console, stdout stream.

Since log.html has a lot of text markups, i prefer to see the log messages as plain text on the console. How to configure this?

Comment: How about `sys.stdout.write("this is a testlib log for robot test - Test.robot")`?

Comment: that is convoluted...i am not a fan of this java like print statements...

Comment: It isn't a "java like print statements" it is _how you write to stdout_.

Comment: Ironman, you comment was helpful to me, my thanks... but i am trying to understand, how robot framework is redirecting the print statements and can the print handler be configured?

Comment: Got it, sorry. Could you add the pybot that you are using? I search Google, and found [this](https://github.com/TommehM/pybot) which doesn't look like what you have.

Comment: i am using `pybot` command that comes with `pip install robotframework`. My command is `pybot Test.robot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robot redefines `sys.stdout`. This is mentioned in the robot framework user's guide in the section labelled [Logging Information](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#logging-information) (see the subtitle "Logging to console".

> Another option, that is only available with Python, is writing
>   messages to sys.__stdout__ or sys.__stderr__. When using this
>   approach, messages are written to the console immediately and are not
>   written to the log file at all

For example:

```
import sys
def robot_print():
   sys.__stdout__.write("this is a testlib log for robot test - Test.robot")
```

Or, if you aren't "a fan of this java like print statements..." (based on your comments to the original question) you can temporarily reassign `sys.stdout`:

```
def robot_print():
    pybot_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    print "this is a testlib log for robot test - Test.robot"
    sys.stdout = pybot_stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I am interested in seeing these print statements in the console, stdout stream.

For this I use [Log to console](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log%20To%20Console) from Builtin library.
Example:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
bi=BuiltIn()
def robot_print():
    bi.log_to_console("this is a testlib log for robot test - Test.robot")
```